# Calling ajax in dynamic page is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I try to call ajax in http://localhost/vv/single_product/21 page it showing an error of

`Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1`

of the JSON data. but when I call the  same function in http://localhost/vv/shop function it works perfectly. here is my code

```
function getvalue(id)
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'manage_qty.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:'id='+id,
            success:function(result){
                var product_qty = $.parseJSON(result);
                var sold = product_qty[0].qty;
                var due = product_qty[1].qty;
                var remain = sold-due;
                var i=0;
                var html="";
                var $select = $(".1-100");
                $select.html('');
                if (remain>0) {
                    for (var i = 1; i <=remain; i++) {

                 $select.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i));
                }

                }else
                {
                    swal("Sorry", "This Product Is Not in Stock", "error");
                }
                
            }
        })
    }
```

I inspect the url I and  found http://localhost/vv/single_product/manage_qty.php... any idea why it is not working in single_product page?

Comment: Open dev tools, make the AJAX request and check the response in the network tab. Whatever is coming back in the response isn't JSON. Most likely this is a discrepancy in the call made which is resulting in the change of response format between pages. As such, we cannot help you debug this with the code shown as it's not inherently a JS issue

Comment: i have cheeked ,found nothing in response..XHR POST http://localhost/vv/single_product/manage_qty.php request id=12(which is right) but response blank.

Comment: One thing i want to ask... why my url like http://localhost/vv/single_product/manage_qty.php, it should be like http://localhost/vv/manage_qty.php according to my Ajax url, isn't it?

Comment: at last, found it... i have to give full path in url..problem solved.